# Export SQL QueryResult to Excell file on Server without installing Office

Tags: sql-server, excel, export-to-excel, openrowset, oledbexception

I want write result rows of a query to a excell file:

```
INSERT into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\temp\testing.xlsx;', 
'SELECT Id,CompanyName FROM [Sheet1$]') 
select Id,CompanyName   from tbl_Company
```

But When Running This query following error occurs :

**Msg 7302, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".**

What is done before running this code :

1 - I installed "2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components"

2 - Executed Configuration Script for using excell :

```
 sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

3 - Change Login Account for SQL Server Service to local account

4 - Added Full Access permission on Excell file folder to local account

5 - Restarted SQL Service

**But my problem remains**

Server : Windows Server 2008

MS Office not installed on server

SQL Server 2014 64bit SP1

Answer (score 0):

I had a mistake :

I should run this configuration script

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1 
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1 
GO
```

also you should be sure to install 64bit version of Access Database Engine (if your sql server is 64bit).